# Handling malformed XML with serde / serde-xml-rs

Tags: rust, error-handling, match, serde

If you have ever used [`serde`](https://serde.rs/), or [`serde-xml-rs`](https://docs.rs/serde-xml-rs/0.5.0/serde_xml_rs/) you've seen [the sample code](https://docs.rs/crate/serde-xml-rs/0.5.0). All of their example code always `upwrap()`s the `from_reader()` function call. But what happens if we need to actually handle errors as it does with the extended example code below?

### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "so-help"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.130"
serde_derive = "1.0.130"
serde-xml-rs = "0.5.0"
```

### src/main.rs

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_xml_rs;

use serde_xml_rs::from_reader;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Item {
    pub name: String,
    pub source: String
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Project {
    pub name: String,

    #[serde(rename = "Item", default)]
    pub items: Vec<Item>
}

fn main() {
    let correct = r##"
        <Project name="my_project">
            <Item name="hello" source="world.rs" />
        </Project>
    "##;
    let project: Project = from_reader(correct.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", project);

    let malformed = r##"
        <Project name="malformed">
            <malformed name="Hello" source="world.rs />
            <WeDontClose This>
        </Project>
    "##;
    let messedup: Project = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", messedup);
}
```

The `malformed` variable contains malformed XML data that causes the `from_reader()` to return an error, but as the examples always use `unwrap()` it's never explained how to handle this error state. So when we run our code we get ...

```
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/so-help`
Project {
    name: "my_project",
    items: [
        Item {
            name: "hello",
            source: "world.rs",
        },
    ],
}
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Syntax { source: Error { pos: 4:13, kind: Syntax("Unexpected token inside attribute value: <") } }', src/main.rs:37:63
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

What I want to do is handle the error with a match statement using idiomatic rust semantics. So I tried to handle that error by replacing this line ...

```
    let messedup: Project = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes()).unwrap();
```

... with these lines ...

```
    let messedup: Project = match from_reader(malformed.as_bytes())
    {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => println!("Error reading malformed xml {:?}", e),
    };
```

... But I get this compile time error ...

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling so-help v0.1.0 (/home/dygear/so-help)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:40:19
   |
40 |         Err(e) => println!("Error reading malformed xml {:?}", e),
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Project`, found `()`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `so-help` due to previous error
```

So how should I be handling parsing errors? I've asked around the rust discord, but no on seems to have an answer for this. The problem seems to be due to the datatype used, but I want that data type to be given back, or an error.

Example code is also [available on github](https://github.com/Dygear/so-help) so you can see exactly where I am.

---

Trying @Lagerbaer's code doesn't actually work.

```
fn main() {
    let correct = r##"
        <Project name="my_project">
            <Item name="hello" source="world.rs" />
        </Project>
    "##;
    let project: Project = from_reader(correct.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", project);

    let malformed = r##"
        <Project name="malformed">
            <malformed name="Hello" source="world.rs />
            <WeDontClose This>
        </Project>
    "##;
    let potentially_messed_up: Result<Project, serde_xml_rs::Error> = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes());
    if let Err(e) = potentially_messed_up {
        println!("Error reading malformed xml {:?}", e);
    } else {
        // now here we do stuff that we _only_ do if there's no error
        potentially_messed_up.unwrap();
        // here we can unwrap without ever causing a panic, because the 
        // if let Err(e) part made sure that we don't enter this branch if 
        // there was an error
    }
    println!("{:#?}", potentially_messed_up);
}
```

Produces this error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `Result<T, serde_xml_rs::Error>`
  --> src/main.rs:42:13
   |
37 |     let potentially_messed_up = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes());
   |         --------------------- consider giving `potentially_messed_up` the explicit type `Result<T, serde_xml_rs::Error>`, with the type parameters specified
...
42 |         let v = potentially_messed_up.unwrap();
   |             ^ cannot infer type

error: aborting due to previous error
```

So we change line 37 now to this ...

```
    let potentially_messed_up: Result<Project, serde_xml_rs::Error> = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes());
```

... Producing this error ...

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `potentially_messed_up`
    --> src/main.rs:47:23
     |
37   |     let potentially_messed_up: Result<Project, serde_xml_rs::Error> = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes());
     |         --------------------- move occurs because `potentially_messed_up` has type `Result<Project, serde_xml_rs::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
42   |         potentially_messed_up.unwrap();
     |                               -------- `potentially_messed_up` moved due to this method call
...
47   |     println!("{:#?}", potentially_messed_up);
     |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
     |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `potentially_messed_up`
help: consider calling `.as_ref()` to borrow the type's contents
     |
42   |         potentially_messed_up.as_ref().unwrap();
     |                               ^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

So we change the statements here ...

```
    let potentially_messed_up: Result<Project, serde_xml_rs::Error> = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes());
    if let Err(ref e) = potentially_messed_up {
        println!("Error reading malformed xml {:?}", e);
    } else {
        // now here we do stuff that we _only_ do if there's no error
        potentially_messed_up.as_ref().unwrap();
        // here we can unwrap without ever causing a panic, because the 
        // if let Err(e) part made sure that we don't enter this branch if 
        // there was an error
    }
    println!("{:#?}", potentially_messed_up);
```

And kinda works, handling `Err` when there is one, but returns an `Ok` wrapped `Project` when there isn't one. That's not quite correct either.

```
Project {
    name: "my_project",
    items: [
        Item {
            name: "hello",
            source: "world.rs",
        },
    ],
}
Ok(
    Project {
        name: "my_project",
        items: [
            Item {
                name: "hello",
                source: "world.rs",
            },
        ],
    },
)
```

---

@Jmb's comment below includes a gist that I followed to to get closer to idiomatic rust, but I can't seem to get that to work either. It handles an error on malformed input, and also the correct input it still is handled in the `Err` match arm. This is weird because it is being read correctly directly above.

```
fn main() {
    let correct = r##"
        <Project name="my_project">
            <Item name="hello" source="world.rs" />
        </Project>
    "##;
    let project: Project = from_reader(correct.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", project);

    let malformed = r##"
        <Project name="malformed">
            <malformed name="Hello" source="world.rs />
            <WeDontClose This>
        </Project>
    "##;

    let correct = r##"
        <Project name="my_project">
            <Item name="hello" source="world.rs" />
        </Project>
    "##;
    let xml = match from_reader(correct.as_bytes())
    {
        Err (e) =>
        {
            println!("Error reading malformed xml {:?}", e);
            return
        }
        Ok(xml) =>
        {
            xml
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}", xml);
}
```

```
warning: unused variable: `malformed`
  --> src/main.rs:31:9
   |
31 |     let malformed = r##"
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_malformed`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.22s
     Running `target/debug/so-help`
Project {
    name: "my_project",
    items: [
        Item {
            name: "hello",
            source: "world.rs",
        },
    ],
}
Error reading malformed xml UnexpectedToken { token: "&XmlEvent::EndElement { .. }", found: "StartElement(Item, {\"\": \"\", \"xml\": \"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace\", \"xmlns\": \"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/\"}, [name -> hello, source -> world.rs])" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised you didn't get an answer, because it should be relatively straightforward.

Your code doesn't compile because you're using the match expression to assign a value to a variable with type `Project` but only one of the match arms actually returns a value of that type, whereas the other match arm doesn't return anything, it just prints stuff.

Let's take it easy and go step by step. `unwrap` is a method of the `Result` enum, with the behavior, as you know, to just return the value if it's there and panic if there was an error.

So if we drop the `unwrap`, what we're left with is a `Result` enum. This is all you need to handle errors, but of course now you have to decide what you want to *do* with the error. In your example, you're printing an error message. But then what should happen after that? Here's what you could do:

```rust
let potentially_messed_up = from_reader(malformed.as_byes());
if let Err(e) = potentially_messed_up {
  println!("Error reading malformed xml {:?}", e);
} else {
  // now here we do stuff that we _only_ do if there's no error
  let v = potentially_messed_up.unwrap();
  // here we can unwrap without ever causing a panic, because the 
  // if let Err(e) part made sure that we don't enter this branch if 
  // there was an error
}
```

Comment: *Large face palm* -- I'm sorry, I'm still getting used to the syntax. Even the `if let Err(e) = potentially_messed_up` surprised me. Are we assigning the error here? The compiler must do some gymnastics to make that syntax work. I'm now wondering if the correct way to handle this is to actually bubble that error up so that the cascade of things that happens after it doesn't.

Comment: The syntax here is one of pattern matching. What happens is that _if_ `potentially_messed_up` has the `Err` variant, we're assigning the contained error value to the variable `e`.

Anyway, you can of course just bubble the error up with the `?` syntax (change your return type to the appropriate `Result` then. The choice depends on the needs of your program.

Comment: @Legerbaer appreciate you taking the time to answer this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Instead of `if let` + `unwrap`, it would be more idiomatic to keep the `match`, but move the processing inside it: [gist](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/ef808cdf3f8edfba65c8b841e7793699).

Comment: @Lagerbaer ... So ... Fun story ... Actually had time to implement this.
`   |'
'37 |     let potentially_messed_up = from_reader(malformed.as_bytes());`
`   |         --------------------- consider giving `potentially_messed_up` the` explicit type `Result<T, serde_xml_rs::Error>`, with the type parameters specified`
`...`
`42 |         let v = potentially_messed_up.unwrap();`
`   |             ^ cannot infer type`

Comment: Well then listen to the compiler and specify the type?